# How to increase hight table cell row according to label size increase in iPad?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

My code does not work the first time when I write long word on textview, then my label size is increases but table height is not increases as par label width and height. What is wrong in my code?

I write  this two line in view didload method

```
Addresslbl  = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(300, 10, 250, 30)];
    Addresslbl.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
```

and Following code write into `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{`

```
if(indexPath.row == 0 && indexPath.section == 3)
        {

                NSString *dispalynotes=@"";
                dispalynotes=Peopledetailmodel.Address;
           // dispalynotes=Addresslbl.text;
                CGSize labelSize = CGSizeMake(200.0, 20.0);

                if ([dispalynotes length] > 0)
                    labelSize = [dispalynotes sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize: 17.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
                return 25.0 + labelSize.height;

        }
```

Comment: You have apply same logic in method heightForRowAtIndexPath

Answer (score 0):

You have apply same logic in method heightForRowAtIndexPath

```
 -(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath  *)indexPath{

 if ([dispalynotes length] > 0)
                labelSize = [dispalynotes sizeWithFont: [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:   17.0] constrainedToSize: CGSizeMake(labelSize.width, 1000) lineBreakMode: UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
            return 25.0 + labelSize.height;

}
```